# Unix Directory Hierarchy Permissions

Tags: unix

Suppose I have a directory with no access for anyone except for root. Am I guaranteed that everything in the directory is inaccessible to everyone but root? In other words, are file permissions hierarchical, so that if a user can't access a directory, they can't access anything in it, even if they have permissions to something in the directory?

Answer (score 6):

Wiile the answer is mostly ***"yes"***, there are special cases in which is can be ***"no"***.

Because unix files are not guaranteed to have a unique path. So if you have

```
$ ls -l
drwx------- 1 root  root [...] root_only
```

and

```
$ ls -l root_only
-rw-rw-rw-- 2 root  root [...] hopefully_private_file
```

and `hopefully_private_file` is hardlinked from elsewhere it *may* be universally readable.

How do you know? Look again at that `ls -l`:

```
$ ls -l root_only
-rw-rw-rw-- 2 root  root [...] hopefully_private_file
            ^
            |
```

The number over the arrow is the link count (for files, it has a different meaning for directories). If the link count is 1 you are safe; if it is something else there may be a problem.

Comment: That's not really fair. Even if the file is hardlinked (and therefore accessible) from somewhere else, you still can't access it from the disallowed path. If the owner of the file hardlinked it from an accessible path, that implies that they understand that now there are two ways of accessing that file.

Comment: @Adam, that *really* depends on what Echostar is trying to achieve here. But people need to be aware of this if they are to understand what the can can can not assume about file accessibility on unix systems. Of course, `chmod 600 hopefully_private_file` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To display something in the directory `dir/` you need `+x` permission to be able to locate the inode of the file. So if you don't have +x, you can't read a file even if it is `777`.

Comment: Hardlinks to the files can break this guarantee. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, removing permissions on a parent directory affects the ability to work with anything within that directory.

If a user does not have execute permission on a directory, they will not be able to see access any files in a directory.

You probably also want to remove the read permission on the directory, so that they won't be able to even see the contents (filenames) of the directory.

Comment: Unless some of the files are hardlinked from a path the user *can* read. See my answer.